# Custom react badge style

Tags: css, reactjs, tabs, bootstrap-5, react-tabs

How can I make a badge/notification inside the tab bootstrap like this? (I use tabs from bootstrap library).

[image]

```
<Tabs
    id="controlled-tab-example"
    activeKey={key}
    onSelect={k => setKey(k)}
    className="app_header"
>
    <Tab eventKey="receiveGift" title="Receive Gift">
        <GifTab />
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="luckyWheel" title="Lucky Wheel"></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: please don't add images of your code

Comment: sorry, I changed it back to mine code @AmilaSenadheera